# $\dot{\mathbf{y}}=A\mathbf{y}$ stability and geometric/algebraic multiplicities

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stability-in-odes

Why $\dot{\mathbf{y}}=A\mathbf{y}$ is stable only when algebraic and geometric multiplicities are the same for every eigenvalue with zero real part?

Answer (score 0):

Because the order 1 system for the linear ODE $y'''=0$ has growing solutions $y=x$ and $y=x^2$.

Comment: Thank you, i'm interested in the case with nonzero imaginary part.

Comment: The same applies. If you want to know it more precisely, look at the exponentials of non-trivial Jordan blocks.